# Oracle 11g - Updating matched rows with values from a source table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

T1.LEID needs to be UPDATED with T1.ID values from 
Rows in which both the MSID and the ESTID match.

I have turned my syntax around and tried several variations, but always end up with same error 01427.

```
UPDATE T1
SET  LEID = (SELECT T2.id
                 FROM T2
                 WHERE   T2.MSID  = T1.MSID )
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT T2.id
          FROM T2
          WHERE T2.ESTID = T1.ESTID
        );

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row


 {       CREATE TABLE T1
(
     { 

    ESTID  NUMBER(8),
      MSID   NUMBER(8),
      SMID   NUMBER(8),
      LEID   NUMBER(8)
    )
    NOLOGGING 
    NOCOMPRESS 
    NOCACHE
    NOPARALLEL
    MONITORING;

    Insert into T1
   (ESTID, MSID, SMID, LEID)
    Values
   (545, 5454, 888, NULL);
    Insert into T1
   (ESTID, MSID, SMID, LEID)
    Values
   (334, 5555, 6541, NULL);
    Insert into T1
   (ESTID, MSID, SMID, LEID)
    Values
   (254, 4487, 888, NULL);
    Insert into T1
   (ESTID, MSID, SMID, LEID)   
    Values
   (659, 54518, 654, NULL);
   Insert into T1
   (ESTID, MSID, SMID, LEID)
   Values
   (854, 8548, 85478, NULL); 
    Insert into T1
   (ESTID, MSID, SMID, LEID)
   Values
   (658, 12485, 254, NULL);
    Insert into T1
   (ESTID, MSID, SMID, LEID)
   Values
   (444, 5555, 888, NULL);
    Insert into T1
   (ESTID, MSID, SMID, LEID)
   Values
   (444, 5545, 888, NULL);
    Insert into T1
   (ESTID, MSID, SMID, LEID)
   Values
   (444, 4444, 888, NULL);
   Insert into T1
   (ESTID, MSID, SMID, LEID)
   Values
   (555, 5555, 999, NULL);
   Insert into T1
   (ESTID, MSID, SMID, LEID)
    Values
   (444, 3333, 5, NULL);
      COMMIT; } 

    CREATE TABLE T2 
    (
    ESTID  NUMBER(8),
    MSID   NUMBER(8),
    ID     NUMBER(8)
    )
    NOLOGGING 
    NOCOMPRESS 
    NOCACHE
    NOPARALLEL
    MONITORING;    }

Insert into T2


    {(ESTID, MSID, ID)
    Values
   (545, 5454, 14);
    Insert into T2
   (ESTID, MSID, ID)
   Values
   (334, 5555, 16);
    Insert into T2
   (ESTID, MSID, ID)
   Values
   (254, 4487, 18);
    Insert into T2
    (ESTID, MSID, ID)
    Values
   (659, 54518, 20);
    Insert into T2
   (ESTID, MSID, ID)
   Values
   (854, 8548, 22);
    Insert into T2
   (ESTID, MSID, ID)
    Values
   (658, 12485, 24);
    Insert into T2
   (ESTID, MSID, ID)
   Values
   (444, 5555, 26);
    Insert into T2
   (ESTID, MSID, ID)
   Values
     (444, 5545, 28);
    Insert into T2
   (ESTID, MSID, ID)
   Values
   (444, 4444, 30);
    Insert into T2
   (ESTID, MSID, ID)
    Values
   (555, 5555, 32);
    Insert into T2
   (ESTID, MSID, ID)
    Values
   (444, 3333, 34);
   COMMIT;  }
```

Would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to alter the scriupt top update the ropws in T1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both columns, MSID and ESTID need to match, the following should do the trick:

```
UPDATE T1
   SET LEID = (SELECT T2.id
                 FROM T2
                WHERE T2.MSID = T1.MSID AND T2.ESTID = T1.ESTID)
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT T2.id
                 FROM T2
                WHERE T2.MSID = T1.MSID AND T2.ESTID = T1.ESTID);     
11 rows updated.
```

Comment: If the tables are larger, I'd use the merge command: `MERGE INTO T1 USING T2 ON (T2.MSID = T1.MSID AND T2.ESTID = T1.ESTID)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET LEID = T2.ID;`

Comment: Both approaches will only work if (MSID, ESTID) is unique in table T2, for instance protected by an unique constraint `ALTER TABLE T2 ADD CONSTRAINT T2_UQ UNIQUE (MSID, ESTID);`

Comment: I was certain I had tried that, but can't find in my history of travails, and it certainly updates the rows in the sample. In the larger tables, still getting dreaded 1427... do the constraints need to be in place, or will the fact that they are unique suffice? I am thinking now in the larger tables they indeed are not unique. Thank you both for your input.

Comment: The tables do hold nearly 100,000 rows each.. Merge would be less overhead?

Comment: {MERGE} works great on the larger tables  as well.... Thank you both once more!!  I did have hiding un-uniqness about.  Once removed, all went smooth.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE T1
   SET LEID = (SELECT T2.id
               FROM T2
               WHERE T2.MSID = T1.MSID AND T2.ESTID = T1.ESTID);

Comment: This query again will throw the same error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row, if the combination of MSID and ESTID in table T2 is not a unique key.